# Merging two data sets by ID in SAS (Data sets inside Library)

Tags: merge, sas

Okay so I have two data sets, one is called Customer and other other CustomerOrder. They are linked by 'CustomerID.' I have both data sets in a sas library referenced as 'NewData.' I want to know how you would write the code to merge these two tables using the library reference and the CustomerID in both sets?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a shot at it, if it doesn't work then show the code you tried and tell us how it didn't work.

Comment: In a data step use the `merge` and `by` statements, or use `proc SQL` and a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the merge in Proc Sql (creating a temporary table called tempCust):

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table work.tempCust as
    select * from 
    NewData.CustomerOrder co,  NewData.Customer cust 

    Where co.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID;
quit;
```